# Gradle fails to resolve the dependency of a dependency marked as 'LATEST'

Tags: java, maven, build, gradle, build.gradle

I have the following **build.gradle** file:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

repositories {
    maven { url "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots" }
    maven { url "http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2" }
}

dependencies {

    compile 'com.skadistats:clarity:1.2',
            'joda-time:joda-time:2.6',
            'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
}
```

And when I try to do a `compileJava` I have the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/tim/Workspace/thedotabot/replay_parser/build.gradle' line: 11

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compile'.
> Could not find com.skadistats:clarity-protobuf:LATEST.
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/skadistats/clarity-protobuf/LATEST/clarity-protobuf-LATEST.pom
      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/skadistats/clarity-protobuf/LATEST/clarity-protobuf-LATEST.jar
      http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/skadistats/clarity-protobuf/LATEST/clarity-protobuf-LATEST.pom
      http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/skadistats/clarity-protobuf/LATEST/clarity-protobuf-LATEST.jar
      http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/skadistats/clarity-protobuf/LATEST/clarity-protobuf-LATEST.pom
      http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/skadistats/clarity-protobuf/LATEST/clarity-protobuf-LATEST.jar
  Required by:
      :replay_parser:1.0 > com.skadistats:clarity:1.2

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

If I checkout the original project from [the repository on Github](https://github.com/skadistats/clarity), switch to the **V1** branch and do a `mvn install` it works fine.

My understanding of the problem is that **clarity** has this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.skadistats</groupId>
    <artifactId>clarity-protobuf</artifactId>
    <version>LATEST</version>
</dependency>
```

And Gradle fails to find it as the version is `LATEST`.

How can I solve this ?

Comment: Gradle holds a cache of dependencies, so can it be the case that it just didn't refresh the latest version of dependency because it already downloaded it? You can force gradle to recheck for the latest versions by using `--refresh-dependencies` from gradle command. Let me know if this resolves your issue

Comment: How can I delete the cache ?

Comment: Gradle cache is under the user_home\.gradle\caches. However, no need to delete it - you can just use the `--refresh-dependencies` flag as I mentioned in my previous comment

Comment: Just tried, it doesn't work ... Same error.

Comment: Does both **clarity** and **clarity-protobuf** reside on the same maven repo?

Comment: Yes they both do : http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cclarity :)

Comment: I think that I got it now. `LATEST` is maven keyword which it is possible that Gradle does not support very well. As a workaround can you try to add an explicit dependency on **clarity-protobuf** and use `latest.release` as the version?

Comment: Reading some more about it, gradle's equivalent to Maven's `LATEST` would be `latest.integration` (take the latest version which can be a Release or a Snapshot version) rather than `latest.release` (which will take only Release versions)

Comment: Great - so I'll formalize it as an answer below

Answer (score 0):

`LATEST` is maven keyword which it is possible that Gradle does not support very well. As a workaround can you try to add an explicit dependency on clarity-protobuf and use `latest.integration` as the version.